Jekins multibranchpipeline and webhook
I am trying to understand the step i need to take to configure a multibranchpipeline using the Job DSL that is triggered on WebHook.
I have consulted the job DSL from my jenkins instance extensively but i could not figure out the way things works.
I'm trying to understand the concepts involved here. I tested and understood the use of PeriodicFolderTrigger. It scan and add a build for any branches that it finds, thus at interval.
What is not clear to me is if i use webhook, what should be the trigger i need to configure in my job DSL.
At the heart of my confusion is:

Is there a way in the job dsl definition to say the trigger is a webhook ?
Is a trigger definition in the job dsl definition necessary for triggering a scan on webhook event ?
Does a webhook trigger a scan and a build ensue, and thus without explicit trigger definition ?
Does it matter to jenkins that the paylod of the webhook event contains the actual branch ref that triggered that build, meaning would it only scan for that branch and nothing else ?

EDIT 1
After some research I understand that i need either gitbranchsource or github integration and it seems both handle the scan and build trigger.

While I understand that there are a bunch of Jenkins questions here,  I believe this question belongs to the DevOps stackexchange.
